# HTML Form only uploads certain files

Tags: php, html

I am making a site that allows users to upload any media files they want (images, videos and audio files). However it seems to be pretty random what the page actually allows me to upload. The form is in `HTML` and the recieveFile script is in `PHP`.

My HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action="recieveFile.php?id=0" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="media" value="Choose file"/>
 <br/><input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

My PHP Recieve script looks like this:

```
if (isset($_FILES['media']))
{
  saveFileFunctions();
}
else
{
  echo "No media files were uploaded!";
}
```

As it is per now I end up in the saveFileFunctions every time I upload an image. It also works with .txt and .pdf. However whenever I tried .mov or .mp4 files it takes me straight to the last echo as if the `$_FILES['media']` is empty. Anyone have any idea why my form only seems send certain files?

Comment: I reckon that the file size exceeds `max_file_upload_size` setting.

Comment: Try checking `$_FILES['file']['error']` see [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: The `$_FILES['file']` does not get set if the file size exceeds around 2M. I changed my `php5/apache/php.ini` to `max_upload_size = 50M` but it will only still accept smaller files.

Comment: There is also a problem when uploading files from around 2MB to 10MB that it will set `$_FILES['media']`, but not the tmp_name parameter, I can still find the extension of the file though. So confused right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are propobly exceeding the maximum filesize allowed to upload files. You need to change that in php.ini:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 20M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 20M
```

You can also do that at runtime in your program

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');
```

Or in a .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

Comment: I tried the ini_set and set it to 50M, but still nothing. It worked nicely without having to do anything on my last server, but I think you are right about the file size, seems to be related.

Comment: Try checking $_FILES['file']['error'] - as suggested by @James Birkett

Comment: I tried changing the `php.ini` file so that I can handle file sizes up to 50MB, but it my php does not seem to get the `$_FILES['media']` unless the file size are less than 2MB.

Comment: @Tom Any chance you can post your `php.ini`?

Comment: Not sure if that is safe, not been fiddling too much with that part.
But it says:
post_max_size = 75M, upload_max_filesize = 50M, max_file_uploads = 20, file_uploads = on, ;upload_tmp_dir =  (note: last point is commented out)

Comment: Does perhaps www-data use it's own php.ini file?

Comment: The php.ini bit was correct, but I had to restart apache. Now it works again. Thanks everyone :)